# Get URL automatically on Google+ Interactive Post

Tags: url, dynamic, google-plus

and thanks in advance. I have tried multiple solutions on here, but none seem to work for what I need to accomplish. I have a website with multiple articles, new ones created regularly. Our site implements the Google+ Interactive Post feature on each article. By adding the following code manually, all works well. What we would like to do is have the data-contenturl and data-calltoactionurl populated with whatever the current page URL is. Additionally, we would like to do the same for the data-prefilltext by using the page's meta description.

Here is an example of the HTML code we use to render the button:

```
<button id="plusshare" 
class="g-interactivepost"
data-contenturl="http://arizonaborderrecon.org/intel/significant-incidents-map"
data-clientid="xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
data-prefilltext="This map shows major incidents involving our border. #significantincidentmap #securetheborder "
data-calltoactionlabel="READ_MORE"
data-calltoactionurl="http://arizonaborderrecon.org/intel/significant-incidents-map">
<i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i>Share this map!</button>
```

Basically, what we are looking to do is replace the two mentioned variables with some kind of code that will automatically get the current page URL so we can eliminate having to put the above code on every article, every time. We would like to place this into a generic HTML module (we use Joomla! as our CMS) so this can be placed on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using **PHP**

```
<?php $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>

<button id="plusshare" 
class="g-interactivepost"
data-contenturl="<?php echo $actual_link; ?>"
data-clientid="xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
data-prefilltext="This map shows major incidents involving our border. #significantincidentmap #securetheborder "
data-calltoactionlabel="READ_MORE"
data-calltoactionurl="<?php echo $actual_link; ?>">
<i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i>Share this map!</button>
```

Comment: Interactive Post comes up, but the "Google Ball" just keeps spinning and the post isn't generated. Do I need to put <?php $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?> in the header or in the body of index.php?

Comment: It's the same... You can actually put as you want. :P `<?php $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>` it's just for initialize the variable to get current URL.

Comment: Awesome! I wonder why the post won't complete it'self. The pop up shows, the autofill data shows, but the colorful ball just keeps spinning. Tried using multiple browsers (cleared cache!) and no dice. Any suggestions? I appreciate the help!

Comment: I saw the second one was missing and added it to the page before you changed the answer lol, thanks for the update! Here is where I am testing this answer: [link] (http://arizonaborderrecon.org/blog/end-of-watch/299-nicholas-j-ivie)

Comment: Yes, by simply copy&paste the URL as such: `data-contenturl="http://mylinkhere.com/somethingelse"` works just fine.

Comment: @JohnSpartan You have an issue! Your HTML output is not your current URL, your output is the PHP code, so I wonder how do you put that code? Look -> **Your HTML:** `data-contenturl="<?php echo $actual_link; ?>"`. Your file is really a _PHP_ file?!

Comment: @FrancisoCarvalho I'm not quite following you. Our site is a PHP based CMS (Joomla!). The end result is HTML is it not? Also, the Javascript version you gave me provides the same results as the previous solutions, everything but the post will show up. You can see what I mean here (JS version): http://arizonaborderrecon.org/blog/end-of-watch/299-nicholas-j-ivie

Comment: Ok, joomla! So, where did you put my code? Was in a _CUSTOM HTML_ module or was in your template _index.php_ file? I already tested my code and the output was something like `data-contenturl="http://www.MYWEBSITE.com"` was I expected.

Comment: I put `<?php $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>` in the index.php file, and `<button id="plusshare" 
class="g-interactivepost"
data-contenturl="<?php echo $actual_link; ?>"
data-clientid="xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
data-prefilltext="This map shows major incidents involving our border. #significantincidentmap #securetheborder "
data-calltoactionlabel="READ_MORE"
data-calltoactionurl="<?php echo $actual_link; ?>">
<i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i>Share this map!</button>` in the article text.

Comment: **1)** The `index.php` it's ok, that won't filter _PHP_ code. **2)** Your article **WILL** filter any _PHP_ code, so the output will be **exactly** your _code_ in text... **3)** Why you put share code in ALL of your articles? Article content should be exactly your article text, without _HIGH_ code (you will have problems of sharing if you presist in that way). Why don't you create a module (need a module that won't block/filter _PHP_ entries - Try [this](http://rumahbelanja.com/serba-serbi/download/Joomla-Project/Flexi-Custom-Code/)) and show it after your article text? This def will works!

Comment: I didn't want to put the share code in every article, which is exactly why I asked about autopopulating the G+ interactive post code. Thanks for the module link, I will give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks guys, the combination of your answers worked perfectly. Much, Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I just discovered that Joomla! has a really awesome API just for this. You can find all the documentation here:
http://api.joomla.org/

That said, I found the following to get the current URL via Joomla! as noted here:
http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/current

`<?php echo JURI::current() . "\n"; ?>`